# Regex convert to convert a string to tab delimited field

Tags: java, regex

I want to convert a string to get tab delimited format. In my opinion option 1 should do it. But it looks like option 2 is actually producing the desired result. Can someone explain why?

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String temp2 = "My name\" is something";
        System.out.println(temp2);
        System.out.println( "\"" + temp2.replaceAll("\"", "\\\"") +"\"");  //option 1
        System.out.println( "\"" + temp2.replaceAll("\"", "\\\\\"") +"\"");  //option 2
        if(temp2.contains("\"")) {
            System.out.println("Identified");
        }
    }
}
```

and the output is:

```
My name" is something
"My name" is something"
"My name\" is something"
Identified
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, you're trying to replace something with a tab, but there are no tabs in your code? Tabs are represented by `\t`

Comment: Seriously.. What is option 2 doing?. What is option 1 doing?. Where is your final delimited string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an Excel compatible CSV format, the escaping of the double quote is *two* double quotes, so called self-escaping.

```
String twoColumns = "\"a nice text\"\t\"with a \"\"quote\"\".";
String s = "Some \"quoted\" text.";
String s2 = "\"" + s.replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\"";
```

And ... no head-ache counting the backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`String#replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) instead of `String#replaceAll()`. The former is a simple string replacement, so it works as you'd expect if you haven't read any documentation or don't know about regular expressions. The latter [interprets its arguments differently](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) because it's a *regex* find-and-replace:

> Note that backslashes (`\`) and dollar signs (`$`) in the replacement string may cause the results to be different than if it were being treated as a literal replacement string.

You'll get this output:

```
My name" is something
"My name\" is something"
"My name\\" is something"
Identified
```